# OBD2 - ELM327 bluetooth simulator

Tags: android, bluetooth, simulator, obd-ii

I am developing Android application for connecting to ELM327 for car unit through Bluetooth. Is there any simulator, to simulate ELM327 on Windows 7 through Bluetooth? So I can test my application without a car.

Comment: can you share some code on how you get data from the device via bluetooth? or some links likevise?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found one working after all. It is called [Obdsim](http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html). It can be run on Windows with bluetooth too.
Just in your bluetooth set incoming bluetooth on some port for example `COM4` then start simulator from your command line:
`obdsim.exe -g gui_fltk -w COM4`

It is nice working simulator with lots of options.

Comment: Can you tell me how to send the commands. As I have installed OBDsim, but I am wondering how can I send commands.

Comment: It seems -w is not a valid option for OSX. Still stuck with no simulator at all. Almost giving up and taking my laptop to the car.

Comment: @Amsik, I am getting an error saying "Error creating virtual port"  when issued the above command in Windows 7

Comment: This Obdsim needs a lot of research for other stuff to get work like virtual COM ports and also in windows 7 bluetooth and virtual port are especially made impossible to use

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about developing such an application, use an OBD2 hardware simulator where you can plug your OBD2 bluetooth adapter in, such as the [DIAMEX OBD2 simulator](http://www.diamex.de/dxshop/Diamex-OBD2-Profi-Simulator-alle-Protokolle). It's a real time-saver and worth every €.

Comment: That said, if you want to get away cheaper, I wrote an app called 'OBD2 Expert' exactly for that purpose. Next to being an OBD2 ScanTool, it allows you to take a capture file (of a vehicle you have inspected before) and simulate an OBD2 BTLE dongle with an iOS device. If you're interested in that, check out a video @ https://www.facebook.com/obd2expert/

Answer (score 0):

I've just found Android app for that, however I'll not test it as it's quite expensive https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=unistep.elm327_emulator

Comment: The link above does not work, but... I used this one and was very suprised how well the app works developing OBDII apps. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beastovest.obd.simulator&hl=en_US